# Sync Jupyter notebook with Python session

Tags: python, spyder, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting to use Python and Jupyter notebook for data analysis. I like Jupyter notebook but I sometimes prefers to use Spyder to have a quick look at the objets saved in memory (variables, dataframes, ...)

That's why I'd like to know if it's possible to have a shared 
workspace between a Python session open in an IDE (like Spyder or Rodeo) and a notebook, so I can share object and avoid executing the same code twice to have the best of both world.

Comment: You can do this with the Qt console (`jupyter  qtconsole --existing`), and Spyder uses that internally, so it might be possible to connect it to an existing kernel.

Answer (score 2):

At least in theory, Spyder supports connecting to an external IPython kernel (e.g. one managed by Jupyter Notebook) via the "Connect to existing kernel" option: https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/ipythonconsole.html

The connection info for that can be obtained as described in http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Connecting%20with%20the%20Qt%20Console.html#Manual-connection

Unfortunately, that isn't actually working for me with Fedora 24's Spyder (2.3.9) and IPython (3.2.1), so I'm marking this answer as Community Wiki.